# Compare Timestamp Difference Between Consecutive Records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How do I compare Timestamp difference between 2 consecutive records?

This is my example:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(ProductID INT, SingleRunFailure bit, SampleDate date);
INSERT @x VALUES
(101, 1, '2016-01-01 10:09:19.617'),    
(101, 0, '2016-01-05 11:09:19.617'),    
(101, 1, '2016-01-07 12:09:19.617'),
(101, 0, '2016-01-09 12:09:19.617'),    
(101, 1, '2016-01-15 13:09:19.617'),    
(101, 0, '2016-01-17 13:09:19.617'),
(101, 0, '2016-01-29 14:09:19.617'),    
(101, 0, '2016-02-02 15:09:19.617');

;WITH cte(ProductID, CCVPassed)
AS
(      
   SELECT ProductID, CASE WHEN SUM(LastTwoRunsPass) >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   FROM (SELECT ProductID, LastTwoRunsPass = CASE WHEN SingleRunFailure = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,           
             RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY SampleDate DESC)
        FROM @x) AS aggregation
   WHERE RowNumber <= 2
   GROUP BY ProductID   
)

SELECT * FROM cte;
```

This returns me a Pass or Fail where SingleRunFailure flag was false on last 2 records.  This part works as expected.

I need to add logic where if the SampleDate difference on the last 2 records was less than 15 minutes return True.

Expected response:

```
ProductID    CCVPassed
101          0
```

This is because the difference between last 2 records is 4 days.  If the SampleDate difference between last 2 records was less than 15 minutes CCVPassed would return 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works like this:

- It gets numbers for each row of each `ProductID` ordered by `SampleDate` ([ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)).
- It only keeps first 2 values (biggest `SampleDate` which are the last 2 rows of the sample)
- It calculates the difference in minutes between the 2 `SampleDate`

**Query:**

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ProductID, SampleDate
        , n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY SampleDate DESC)
    FROM @x
)
SELECT ProductID
    , CCVPassed = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(SampleDate), MAX(SampleDate)) < 15 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM cte
WHERE n <= 2
GROUP BY ProductID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/def45/1/0)

**Output:**

```
ProductID   CCVPassed
101 4       false
```

Note:

- It partitions by `ProductId` because it supposed you have several `ProductId` in your real table.
- Replace true/false by 1/0 or whatever is needed in the real query